# Manual background div slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, background, slideshow, fade

I need to make a css background image fade slideshow. For several reasons, i cannot have a physical div in my html. It's the body with a class called -home- that has a current background. There will be 4 pictures for the slideshow, no more, no less, so that doesn't have to dynamic.

I already have the following jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var original_image = '#000000 url(images/bg_home.jpg) top center no-repeat';
    var second_image = '#000000 url(images/bg_home2.jpg) top center no-repeat';
    var third_image = '#000000 url(images/bg_home3.jpg) top center no-repeat';
    var fourth_image = '#000000 url(images/bg_home4.jpg) top center no-repeat';

    $('.home').click(function() {
        $(this).css('background', second_image);
    });
});
</script>
```

So, as you see this is a very simple script that only works if i click the general -home- div. Can anyone help me with transforming this into a simple fade slideshow without any click? It should just start executing the fade slideshow onload.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:

```
$(function(){
   var images = [
       'bg_home.jpg',
       'bg_home2.jpg',
       'bg_home3.jpg',
       'bg_home4.jpg' 
   ],
   loop = 0,
   $home = $('.home');

   (function fader(){
        $home
        .fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $home.css('background', '#000000 url(' + images[loop] + ') top center no-repeat');
            $home.fadeIn('fast', function(){
                 setTimeout(fader, 3000);
            });
        });

        if(loop < images.length) 
           loop++;
        else loop = 0;                
    })();         
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It certainly does something, although not quite right. What happens right now, is onload the image shows up for about a millisecond, fading into black. And then the 'images' (although black) are fading.

Comment: @Mathijs: it should work, I created an example here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Yjm89/

Comment: Yes, indeed, it does work! I just have to finetune it a bit. Thanks! Only one thing: there's a black image in between, a picture called 'undefined'.

Comment: @Mathijs: should be because I created a little bug. It should be `images.length - 1` in the `if statement`.

Comment: Yes, i figured it out myself :-) Thanks for you help, really!